# waitForImages Plugin - not waiting

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery/js code is not waiting for images loaded to fade out. What is the problem?

```js
$('#entry').css('background-image','url(../img/backg3.jpg)').waitForImages(function() {
    $('#load').fadeOut(1000);
 $('.spinner').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

```css
 /*******************

Loading

*********************/

 #load {
  position:absolute;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw; 
  background-color:#ddd;
  z-index:1000;
  /*-moz-transition:all 2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition:all 2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition:all 2s ease-out;
  transition:all 2s ease-out;*/
 }
 
 @-o-keyframes spin {
   100%{
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
  }

 @-moz-keyframes spin {
   100%{
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
  }

 @-webkit-keyframes spin {
   100%{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
  }

 @keyframes spin {
   100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
  }

 .spinner {
  position:absolute;
  top:45vh;
  left:45vw;
  width:5vh;
  height:5vh;
  border: 6px solid #F90;
  border-left-color:#FC3;
  border-bottom-color:#FF6;
  border-right-color:transparent;
  border-radius:100%;
  animation: spin 400ms infinite linear;
  margin: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div id="load">
  <div class="spinner"></div> 
</div>
```

So I want while my background image is loading to hold the spinner, but it fade outs without image.

Page - http://sarosacramento.com/
Plugin - https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

Comment: Can you recreate your problem in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: you can see here: http://www.sarosacramento.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their github page, it looks like you're supposed to apply `.waitForImages()` to an element selector (which either has image children or images in its CSS).  In your code, instead of applying it to the selector, you're first adding CSS, then trying to apply `.waitForImage()`, which won't work, since the .css() doesn't return a selector.  Try instead:

```
$('#entry').waitForImages(function () {
    $('#load').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.spinner').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

for the JS and just put the background image in normal CSS:

```
#entry {
  background-image: url(../img/backg3.jpg);
}
```

(If you must set it via JS, do that before applying .waitForImages() to $("entry"):

```
$('#entry').css('background-image','url(../img/backg3.jpg)');
$('#entry').waitForImages(function () { ...
```

though I haven't actually tested this.)

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9t6kvk/2/.  (It mostly uses your code, but I used some different images that wouldn't be in our caches already.  But since the first one might already be loading while JSFiddle is "initializing the awesome", there are some backups for subsequent "Run"s.)

Comment: `css()` with 2 arguments *does* return something the plugin can use.